# How to d arrow icon exactly like in image? css

Tags: css, sass, icons

how do I make an icon look like this? Using css:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Alex, you can do it in many ways. If you don't want to depend on an external library you could use unicode arrows for that and style your icon as you like.

```css
i.arrow::before {
  content: '|< ⟶';
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #af8564;
  background-color: #fff5e8;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<i class="arrow"></i>
```

Comment: This is solved my problem. Just one more think, How to set this line little more bigger? -----> :D

Comment: And one more How do this but in left side ? <---- ? 
And what is symbol? 
Answear me this and I will check answear soled

Comment: You can use plenty of symbols from unicode http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html, those symbol are characters, that means that you can change size, color and form like you do with letters.